# Are the type bigger than unsigned long long int in c?

Tags: c

My data range is `N (0 ≤ N  <  10^1,000,000)`

I am using `unsigned long long int`, but it's not enough for my data.

Please suggest the data type I should use.

Comment: For whatever you are trying to do, there is already software out there for it and you should try to find it rather than reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Note: you might want to consider using GMP floats with reasonable a precision instead of integers as `10^1000000` would take ~3MiB to store as an integer. Disregarding the memory requirements, *computing* on ~3MiB integers would be very slow.

Comment: `uintmax_t` _may_ be wider integer type than `unsigned long long`.  Is so, maybe only 2x the width of `unsigned long long`, but that is far less than `10^1,000,000`.